# Facebook App  Game Canvas Size

Tags: facebook

I am building a Facebook App Game and was wondering what a safe height and width for my canvas.  I know that the current standard is 760 and there are questions about that, but I would like to know what a good height would be.  I would like it to take into account smaller screen sizes.  My game is a sidescroller.

I know there are a few Facebook App questions similar to this but I feel mine is different because I am concerned with the height in addition to the width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your **aspect ratio**. For normal screens this is either approximately 4:3 (Standard TV or monitor) or 16:9 (Widescreen). There's slight variations on this like 16:10 as well, but the two above are a good guide.

If you're creating a side-scroller, I'd imagine it's the left-right that matters more than the top-bottom. I'd suggest a widescreen format, so **around the 420-430 mark** will do for height.

**In terms of small screen resolutions**: if you're happy with 760 then you don't really need to go any lower than 420. Since most monitors will have at worst this 16:9 resolution, if it can fit 760 across then it can fit 420 down. Even a really old resolution like 800x600 can fit it comfortably.

If you're talking about supporting phones or people making their Facebook window take up half the monitor rather than the full amount, then I'd check out [this tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/gopherwoord-studios-resizing-html5-games/) on resizing your game dynamically. You want to **keep your aspect ratio constant** and resize the whole thing to make the game as big as it can be.

Comment: thanks! I wasn't actually going to make it playable on a mobile version but now I might take it into account!

Comment: I'm not sure how well mobile Facebook works with apps, but you can definitely have sign-in through Facebook and an externally hosted version (that just happens to optimise for mobiles :))

Comment: Another quick note: You don't need to go lower than 420, but it can provide a nice effect. If you're not using that screen space anyway then you can give the impression that the world is longer (or you're seeing more of it) by shrinking that height. Conversely though, my intuition says that an app that takes up more real estate of the screen feels more like a quality app. I reckon (and it's pure hypothesising) that if you reduce it too much it'll just feel like a banner and not like a quality game. Verdict: Experiment and see how it feels.

Comment: Yeah I think I might use platforms and things so that the game play isn't purely horizontal, making the game a little more interesting.